# boot troubles with hyper v on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, virtualization

My OS is Windows 8.1 Pro and my processor is core i7, x64.

I know I've got the requirements to run Hyper-V, because I've already done it on the same machine but few days after installing all the stuff, my camputer refused to boot!

I've turned on the Windows features Hyper-V and Hyper-V Platform. My virtualization technologies is disabled in my BIOS, because if it isn't, my camputer doesn't reboot. So, when I try to start my virtual machine I've got the error message saying hypervisor isn't running.
i've also updated my bios (by holding win+b as the machine is booting).

If i uncheck only Hyper-V Platform and let the other 2 options it reboots but can't connect to locolhost. It says it doesn't find the object name locolhost.

i just would like to create virtuals machines ,What have I done wrong or forgotten? here is the specification of my labtop
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=uk&lc=en&docname=c03892352

here is my motherboard
Board: Hewlett-Packard 1972 95.32
Serial Number: PDPWT048J4Y842
Bus Clock: 100 megahertz
UEFI: Insyde F.21 12/04/2013

Comment: The virtualization feature needs to be enabled its a requirement for Hyper-V try another virtual machine software

Comment: my question is how does it come?if i enable virtualization technologies in BIOS i will have to disable hyper-v platform to be able to boot

Comment: Please rephrase your question

Comment: which motherboard do you use?